# unable to find out the mistake in deleting last node of a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am unable to find out my mistakes in this code.
unable to delete last node from a single linked list properly.
click below for the code
https://github.com/Malaya2184/PY100/blob/master/data%20structure/allinone.py

Comment: Note that in order to delete the last node of a linked list you will have to find the second last node and make it last (e.g. by setting its `next` value to `None`)

Answer (score 0):

Next time please show your code instead of linking your github account.

You are iterating to the last node, and then setting the `data` to `None` (since the `current.next` is `None`).
You want to set the `next` value of the node before the last one to `None` instead.